# Программа возвращает пустой файл

Tags: python

```
zapret=['_','#']

#ОТСЕИВАНИЕ НЕВАЛИДНЫХ ПАРОЛЕЙ
def zapinline(line, zapret):
    for sym in zapret:
        if line.find(sym) != -1:
            return 1
        else:
            continue
    else:
        return 0
    
         

inputfile='password.txt'
outputfile='done_passwords.txt'

infile=open(inputfile, mode='r', encoding='UTF-8')
outfile=open(outputfile, mode='w', encoding='UTF-8')
for line in infile:
#Построчно проверяет докумет
    if len(line)>=6 and zapinline(line,zapret)==0:
        outfile.write(str(line))
    else:
        continue
```

Входные данные:

```
Normalniy
Kor
S Probelom
VtoroyNormalniy
S_Procherkom
S#Zvezdoy
```

Ожидаемый результат: Normalniy S Probelom VtoroyNormalniy

Полученный результат: Пустой выходной файл

Пожалуйста, укажите на ошибку и буду очень благодарен, если подскажете как сделать это более красиво. Думаю, что проблема где-то в функции zapinline, т.к. если удаляю её, то всё норм, хотя проблема возникает даже, если я нигде не вызываю эту функцию.
Заранее прошу прошения, если вопрос покажется тупым или там будет какая-то банальная ошибка, но я её не вижу(

Comment: Так как вы написали `else: return 0`, после цикла, то значит функция вернёт 0 только если список zapret будет пуст и цикл не отработает (это очевидно не так). И раз этот zapret не пуст и цикл работает всегда, то значит функция для корректных паролей возвращает `None`, проверка `None==0` проваливается и код `outfile.write` никогда не будет выполнен

Comment: очень советую вам прочесть [pep8 на русском](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) или [официальный pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (слёзно вас прошу)

Comment: И до кучи str(line) тут str лишнее, там и так строка, но это так, мелочи.

Comment: может использовать regex?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zapinline так сложно написана, что даже непонятно,  что она делает. Вот простой и понятный вариант:

```
def zapinline(line):
    for sym in zapret:
        if sym in line:
            return True # есть запретный символ 
    return False
```

И не забывайте закрывать файлы.

Comment: Без использования with - однозначно забудет! )

Comment: `return bool(set(line) & set(zapret))` (впрочем, эта строчка тоже непонятно что делает)

Comment: @andreymal ну это уже небольшой хардкор :)